# When is Cartier dual of a finite group etale?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

I am trying to solve the following exercise from *Waterhouse: Introduction to affine group schemes* (Chapter 6, Ex. 12 on page 53) without any success.

Let $char(k)=p >0$ and let $G$ be an abelian etale finite group scheme.  Show that $G^D$ (Cartier dual of $G$) is etale iff $\dim_k(k[G])$ is prime to $p$.

I can see this if $G=\mathbb Z/n$, but not in general.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce to the case when $G=\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$ easily by noting that

**a)** Cartier duality commutes with with base change.

**b)** Over a separably closed field every etale group scheme is constant.

**c)** Cartier duality commutes with products.